# Dragging anchors with :active CSS in Firefox/IE breaks CSS anchor behavior

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, anchor

In Firefox and IE, when an anchor with a CSS `:active` state is dragged and the mouse button is released, the normal go-to-url does not occur nor does the anchor return to its normal :link state. After this, :hover state does not trigger on the anchor either. So I'm basically stuck with an anchor that is perpetually :active until the mouse is clicked somewhere else in the window.

This odd behavior does not occur in Chrome. Is there a fix for this? Should I just use `div`s instead of anchors?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain of the specs for CSS, as I haven't read them in any detail whatsoever, but this isn't a new thing for Firefox - it's always been that way. There is, however, an addon that functions sort of like what you're asking for - DragUrLink: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12721/

Comment: What I really want is for the anchor to either go to the url if the mouse is released inside the anchor or to revert to its normal :link state if the mouse leaves the anchor. The addon while helpful won't help any visitors of my site =[. If this is the case I may have to just use divs instead. Thanks.